# R Markdown knit to PDF error: kable_latex() unused argument (rownames.name = "")

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, kableextra

I am trying to knit my R Markdown file to a PDF. I have the most update version of RStudio and R installed.

Every time I try to render my document, it throws this error:

```
Quitting from lines 73-74 [data3] (MyDoc.Rmd)
Error in `kable_latex():
! unused argument (rownames.name = "")
Backtrace:
  1. rmarkdown::render(...)
  2. knitr::knit(knit_input, knit_output, envir = envir, quiet = quiet)
  3. knitr:::process_file(text, output)
  7. knitr:::process_group.block(group)
  8. knitr:::call_block(x)
     ...
 20. knitr (local) fun(x, options = options)
 23. printr:::knit_print.table(x, ...)
 25. printr:::knit_print.matrix(...)
 27. knitr::kable(...)
 28. base::do.call(...)
Execution halted
```

These are the current libraries I have on my document:

```
rm(list=ls())
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tibble)
library(tinytex)
library(kableExtra)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)
library(knitr)
library(ggplot2)
library(doBy)
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)
library(printr)
library(xtable)
library(gmodels)
library(survival)
library(pander)
library(psych)
library(questionr)
library(DT)
library(data.table)
library(expss)
options(xtable.floating = FALSE)
options(xtable.timestamp = "")
library(magrittr)
library(Hmisc)
library(forestmangr)
library(stats)
library(gridExtra)
library(yaml)
library(boot)
library(table1)
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling packages to see if that would fix the problem. One thing I came across was that it would not let me install the `knitr` package. Every time I attempt to do so, a pop-up window appears stating:

```
Updating Loaded Packages
One or more of the packages to be updated are currently loaded.
Restarting R prior to install is highly recommended.

RStudio can restart R before installing the requested packages.
All work and data will be preserved during restart.

Do you want to restart R prior to install?
```

I click "Yes", but it never completes the installation. It just runs, and the same pop-up window shows up over and over. I think this is tied to my issue, but don't know how to resolve this.

I get the same exact error message and problem when I try to knit to HTML or Word.

Comment: Can you `dput(yourdata)`, maybe the issue is related to your data!

Comment: This is a bug of knitr, which [I just fixed](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/commit/547b7cd6b818d06eb9261c8245bb37f7654fc844). Thanks for the report! You can install the dev version via `remotes::install_github('yihui/knitr')`.

Comment: My data is nit the issue, as when I knit the PDF after removing the "kableExtra" library, it is able to output a PDF.

Comment: The dev version solved my issue. Thanks!